# Action and pass variable to all actions in symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony1

I want to make some action (php script) before all actions in my frontend app and then pass a result from that script to actions in variable - so I can get variable value from all actions. Where should I declare sth like this?

Answer (score 3):

If the filter solution dont feet your needs, you can also create a base action class with a preExecute function:

```
// app/frontend/lib/baseActions.class.php

class baseActions extends sfActions
{
   public function preExecute()
   {
      $this->myVar = .... // define your vars...
   }
}
```

Then your module actions class extends your baseActions class:

```
// app/frontend/modules/myModule/actions/actions.class.php

class myModuleActions extends baseActions
{
   public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
   {
      // var $this->myVar is available in any action and in your template
      ... 
   }
}
```

if you have to use the preExecute function in your module class action, remember to call `parent::preExecute()` in it.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of information ?

I would recommend you to use [filters](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_filters).

In your `apps/frontend/config/filters.yml`:

```
rendering: ~
myfilter:
  class: myCustomFilter
```

Create the file `lib/filter/myCustomFilter.php`:

```
<?php
class myCustomFilter extends sfFilter
{
  public function execute ($filterChain)
  {
    if ($this->isFirstCall())
    {
      // do what ever you want here.
      $config = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Config')->findAll();
      sfConfig::set('my_config', $config);
    }

    $filterChain->execute();
  }
}
```

And then, every where, you can retrieve your data:

```
sfConfig::get('my_config');
```