# symfony 1.4 reuse variable declared in component.class.php

Tags: templates, variables, action, symfony-1.4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Action and pass variable to all actions in symfony 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210784/action-and-pass-variable-to-all-actions-in-symfony-1-4)

I have a variable declared in a component included in the main layout.

```
$this->var
```

which is accessible with $var in the template corresponding to the component

```
_component.php
```

how can i make this variable accessible in another template.

Comment: You can't, but your can use session for that. What's inside `$var`?

Comment: $var is the result of a query.

Comment: maybe we can declare "globals" variables for all the page...including components, actions, ...

Comment: Does this query need to be execute on each page? Does the content can change for a given session?

Comment: I think I have found the solution in another of your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210784/action-and-pass-variable-to-all-actions-in-symfony-1-4 ;)

Comment: That's basically where I will let you go when you will answer me :-)

Comment: yes the query need to be executed on every page. As you suggest in the other post, I choose to implement the filter way. Thank you for your help